# Nodejs streams and transformers unexpected behaviour after first execution

Tags: node.js, express, csv, stream, transform

I am trying to create a pipeline that parses a csv file against certain conditions (hypothetically is `filtersRedundancy` transformer). This is an express app, when the endpoint is called twice it freezes the second time with no returned response.

```
const filtersRedundancy = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      callback(null, Object.assign({}, chunk, {chunked_1:true}));
    }
  });

  const justPrintTransformer = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      console.log(chunk)
      this.push(chunk);
      callback();
    }
  });

app.post('/upload_customers', (req, res)=>{
    const reader = fs.createReadStream('./testfile0.csv')
        .pipe(csvParser({headers:['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M']}))
        .pipe(filtersRedundancy)
        .pipe(justPrintTransformer)
        .on('finish', ()=>{
            console.log('Finished');
            res.send('OK')
        })
        .on('error', ()=>{
            res.send('error')
        })
    })
```

An explaination for this behaviour